# How to move cell without NSIndexPath in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am going to move a cell from a section to another in UITableView. The problem is that I don't know the index path of this cell. (Or in other words, I have an index path for this cell but the index path is likely out of date now). Instead, I have a reference point to this cell. How can I move this cell?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "a reference point to this cell"? Cells are reused, so if you mean a pointer to a particular cell, that probably won't do you any good.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, you are right. Cells may be out of date too. So I can't move cells without a valid index path?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you even mean by "moving cells". You can move the data to wherever you want by rearranging the order in your array. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: @rdelmar What you say is my current solution. Problem is that has no animation with reloading table view.

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to see the cell slide up or down into a new location (like when a user drags a row)? Where do you want it to move to -- since you don't know its current indexPath, do you know what indexPath you want it to end up at?

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry for late. I want to move cell from one section to another with animation. The destination indexPath is unknow too. I am going to remove the cell from current section and insert a new cell to destination section to simulate move cell. of course with updating my data source first.

Comment: So I assume you want to move a cell based on the data it contains? How are you going to move it if you don't know where it's going? Where are you going to insert it? You don't have to simulate the move, you can use moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: to move the row without doing a deletion and insertion (in the table view that is -- you still have to do that in your array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to move a row based on finding a certain string in the cell to the top of section 1.

```
@implementation TableController {
    NSInteger selectedRow;
    NSMutableArray *theData;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0);
    NSMutableArray *colors = [@[@"Black", @"Brown", @"Red", @"Orange", @"Yellow",@"Green", @"Blue"] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *nums = [@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five", @"Six", @"Seven", @"Eight"] mutableCopy];
    theData = [@[colors, nums] mutableCopy];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return theData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [theData[section] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (section == 0)? @"Colors" : @"Numbers";
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}



-(IBAction)moveRow:(id)sender {
    NSString *objToMove = @"Red";

    // Find the section that contains "Red"
    NSInteger sectionNum = [theData indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSArray *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj containsObject:objToMove];
    }];

    // Find the row that contains "Red"
    NSInteger rowNum = [theData[sectionNum] indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:objToMove];

    if (sectionNum != NSNotFound && rowNum != NSNotFound) {
        [theData[sectionNum] removeObjectIdenticalTo:objToMove];
        [theData[1] insertObject:objToMove atIndex:0];
        [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNum inSection:sectionNum] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution to find fresh indexpath from data source. thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the cell's object then you can simply get its indexpath.

```
UITableViewCell *cellObject; //provided that you have a reference to it.
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cellObject];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test your code tonight. BTW, `[tableView indexPathForCell:cellObject]` may return nil if cell is not visible?

Comment: No it wont i think, at-least for me it did not.